# problem with uitableview dynamic height adjusting correctly

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am working on a project that has a uitableview with 3 rows in 1 section. Now, is what I would like to do is to be able to have *1* of those 3 cells be dynamic in height. First off, I don't even know if thats possible. If it is, then I want to do it! I found a very useful tutorial helping me through it, [here](http://www.raddonline.com/blogs/geek-journal/iphone-sdk-resizing-a-uitableviewcell-to-hold-variable-amounts-of-text/). I implemented the StringHelper files he recommended, and they work great for one cell, but when there are multiple cells, I begin to have issues. This picture illustrates what happens when I save the text:[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e7351da3ea.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e7351da3ea.png)

And as you can see for whatever reason randomly inserts a nice little arab looking symbol at the beginning.

So, here is the code I am working with:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{  
NSString *label = [entree.notes/*putting entree.notes here may or may not be correct*/ length]  == 0 ? kDefaultNoteLabel : aNote;
CGFloat height = [label RAD_textHeightForSystemFontOfSize:kTextViewFontSize] + 40.0;
return height;
}  


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
 cell.editingAccessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
  }
aNote = entree.notes; 
NSString *label = [aNote length] == 0 ? kDefaultNoteLabel : aNote;
switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0: 
 cell.textLabel.text = @"Name";
 cell.detailTextLabel.text = entree.title;
break;
    case 1:
cell.textLabel.text = @"Date";
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:entree.date];
break;
    case 2:
 //aNote = entree.notes;
 if ([[cell.contentView subviews] count] > 0) {
   id view = [[cell.contentView subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
   UILabel *labelToSize = view;
   [label RAD_resizeLabel:labelToSize WithSystemFontOfSize:kTextViewFontSize];
 } else {
   UILabel *cellLabel;
  cellLabel = [label RAD_newSizedCellLabelWithSystemFontOfSize:kTextViewFontSize];
  [cell.contentView addSubview:cellLabel];
  [cellLabel release];
 }

  cell.textLabel.text = @"Notes";
  cell.detailTextLabel.text = entree.notes;// description];
  break;
 }
  return cell;
}
```

Where entree is the name of my NSManaged Object, and title, date, notes are the attributes. All I need is to be able to set cell 3, or the notes attribute to a dynamic height so that when they input large amounts of text, that cell and only that cell moves, and everything else stays the same. As you can see, I have been trying some things, I apologize if it has gotten kind of messy, but this current setup of code, produces the images above, which is close, but not quite there. It may just be a quick fix, so if anyone out there can help me out, it would be *greatly*  appreciated! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a blog post on this as well that provides code for multiple cells. You can read it on [Cocoa Is My Girlfriend](http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/).

Your code in your answer is unreadable because you didn't format it correctly. You'll probably get more/better feedback if you fix that.

Best Regards.

Comment: This question is even more fun since there is a documented limit to how tall cells can be. See the UITableViewDelegate documentation.